# Operation could destabilize runtime Insight.Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, insight.database

I am using Insight.Database in asp.net webforms project developed in vs 2010.

This error occurs in windows shared hosting hosted in hostgator.com and the .net framework version is 4.

The class which throws error works good in local System.
  [image]

The class structure is

```
    public class Class_Curvature
{
    /// <summary>
    /// gets or sets the Curvature serial number
    /// </summary>
    public int Curv_Slno { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// gets or sets the Curvature Code
    /// </summary>
    public string Curv_Code { get; set; }

     /// <summary>
    /// gets or sets the Curvature Description
    /// </summary>
    public string Curv_Description { get; set; }

     /// <summary>
    /// gets or sets the Curvature status
    /// </summary>
    public string Del_Status { get; set; }

}
```

Any help?

**edit stack trace**

```
[VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.]
   CreateInputParameters-6f4ac4bb-e3e3-4b00-99e1-7b9b97d8013b(IDbCommand , Object ) +6
   Insight.Database.DBCommandExtensions.AddParameters(IDbCommand cmd, Object parameters) in DBCommandExtensions.cs:31
   Insight.Database.DBConnectionExtensions.CreateCommand(IDbConnection connection, String sql, Object parameters, CommandType commandType, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, IDbTransaction transaction) in DBConnectionExtensions.cs:276
   Insight.Database.<>c__DisplayClass5f`1.<Query>b__5d(IDbConnection c) in DBConnectionExtensions.cs:498
   Insight.Database.DBConnectionExtensions.ExecuteAndAutoClose(IDbConnection connection, Func`2 getCommand, Func`3 translate, CommandBehavior commandBehavior) in DBConnectionExtensions.cs:1455
   Insight.Database.DBConnectionExtensions.Query(IDbConnection connection, String sql, Object parameters, IQueryReader`1 returns, CommandType commandType, CommandBehavior commandBehavior, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, IDbTransaction transaction, Object outputParameters) in DBConnectionExtensions.cs:497
   Insight.Database.DBConnectionExtensions.QuerySql(IDbConnection connection, String sql, Object parameters, CommandBehavior commandBehavior, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, IDbTransaction transaction, Object outputParameters) in DBConnectionExtensions.cs:580
   Insight.Database.SqlInsightDbProvider.AdjustSqlParameters(SqlCommand command) in SqlInsightDbProvider.cs:342
   Insight.Database.SqlInsightDbProvider.DeriveParametersFromStoredProcedure(IDbCommand command) in SqlInsightDbProvider.cs:108
   Insight.Database.Providers.<>c__DisplayClass3.<DeriveParameters>b__0(IDbConnection _) in InsightDbProvider.cs:142
   Insight.Database.DBConnectionExtensions.ExecuteAndAutoClose(IDbConnection connection, Func`2 getCommand, Func`3 translate, CommandBehavior commandBehavior) in DBConnectionExtensions.cs:1455
   Insight.Database.Providers.InsightDbProvider.DeriveParameters(IDbCommand command) in InsightDbProvider.cs:136
   Insight.Database.CodeGenerator.DbParameterGenerator.CreateClassInputParameterGenerator(IDbCommand command, Type type) in DbParameterGenerator.cs:181
   Insight.Database.CodeGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetInputParameterGenerator>b__0(QueryIdentity key) in DbParameterGenerator.cs:151
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +72
   Insight.Database.CodeGenerator.DbParameterGenerator.GetInputParameterGenerator(IDbCommand command, Type type) in DbParameterGenerator.cs:142
   Insight.Database.DBCommandExtensions.AddParameters(IDbCommand cmd, Object parameters) in DBCommandExtensions.cs:31
   Insight.Database.DBConnectionExtensions.CreateCommand(IDbConnection connection, String sql, Object parameters, CommandType commandType, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, IDbTransaction transaction) in DBConnectionExtensions.cs:276
   Insight.Database.<>c__DisplayClass57.<Execute>b__55(IDbCommand _, IDataReader __) in DBConnectionExtensions.cs:328
   Insight.Database.DBConnectionExtensions.ExecuteAndAutoClose(IDbConnection connection, Func`2 getCommand, Func`3 translate, CommandBehavior commandBehavior) in DBConnectionExtensions.cs:1461
   Insight.Database.DBConnectionExtensions.Execute(IDbConnection connection, String sql, Object parameters, CommandType commandType, Boolean closeConnection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, IDbTransaction transaction, Object outputParameters) in DBConnectionExtensions.cs:324
   ICurvature9571f690-6058-4917-8371-a50f3c3cd056.usp_CurvatureInsert(Class_Curvature objName) +31
   Crud_Curvature.Insert_Curvature(Class_Curvature cls) in d:\inetpub\vhosts\qsqpl.com\microsharp.qsqpl.com\App_Code\2_Sales\Class_Curvature.cs:113
   _2_Sales_Curvature.SaveData() in d:\inetpub\vhosts\qsqpl.com\microsharp.qsqpl.com\2_Sales\Curvature.aspx.cs:92
   _2_Sales_Curvature.btnSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\inetpub\vhosts\qsqpl.com\microsharp.qsqpl.com\2_Sales\Curvature.aspx.cs:68
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9628442
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: @sansknowledge Can you share a proper screenshot or paste stack trace

Comment: added full stack trace as requested.